# How to find the min and max of a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, python, hash, 2d, rect

I'm following this article here:

https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/spatial-hashing-r2697

creating my spatial hashing function to solve a slowness problem in my 2D game in collision detection. But I did not understand the part of inserting the object:

How do I find the min and max of the object below?

```
myObject = {
    x: 704,
    y: 448,
    width: 32,
    height: 32
}
```

I dropped python a few years ago, and forgot its syntax, it's meaning what with the code below:

```
def insert_object_for_box(self, box, object):

# hash the minimum and maximum points

min, max = self._hash(box.min), self._hash(box.max)

# iterate over the rectangular region

for i in range(min[0], max[0]+1):

for j in range(min[1], max[1]+1):

# append to each intersecting cell

self.contents.setdefault( (i, j), [] ).append( object )
```

would this be in javascript:

```
function insert_object_for_box(box, object) {

    box.min.x = here?;
    box.min.y = here?;
    box.max.x = here?;
    box.max.y = here?;

    var minX = this.hash(box.min.x);
    var minY = this.hash(box.min.y);

    var maxX = this.hash(box.max.x);
    var maxY = this.hash(box.max.y);

    for(var x = minX; x < maxX+1, x++) {
        for(var y = minY; y < maxY+1, y++) {
             here?
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't a rectangle with same width than height a square ? `Math.min` and `Math.max` function will help you get min and max value though

Comment: @Zyigh but I do not understand the maximum and minimum where? do x or y? I did not understand what he meant by min and max there in the article.

Comment: @Zyigh I edited the question